# Creating unique index in MongoDB with type integer

Tags: mongodb, types, unique-index

I want to create a simple collection that stores statistics of different devices.
Each device has a unique device id. I want to enforce the uniqueness so I thought to create a unique index for the device id field, But I didn't figured how to tell the collection that this field is of type number.

For example I can receive query with device id '0x3f', '0x0003f', '3f'... and all of them need to match to the same document.
I can parse the request before querying the DB but to me it's not sound like the right solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *not* worrying about this in Mongo, but instead trying to handle it in your application layer which is calling Mongo.  For example, in JavaScript, appreciate that using any hex literal translates to the same integer value:

```js
var i = 0x3f;
var j = 0x0003f;

if (i == 63) {
    console.log("0x3f = 63");
}
if (j == 63) {
    console.log("0x0003f = 63");
}
```

That is, just let the application marshall the hex literal into an integer value, then pass that int value to Mongo.

Comment: Hi. thank you for the answer. 
I thought to deal with that in my application, but I thought that maybe I'm missing something. MongoDB is new to me, it's the first time I use it. From your answer I understand that there is no better solution